# UndefinedVariable python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code, and the error is very silly (I don't think the selenium have anything to do with it), but i've tried a lot of things and nothing works. What can I do?
THE ERROR IS IN THE VARIABLES NAME "sHoras"

```
class Clima():

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
website = "https://weather.com/?Goto=Redirected"
path = "C:/Users/Administrador/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(path))
driver.get(website)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "truste-button3"))).click()
time.sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'LanguageSelector--LanguageSelectorStatus--mXkYQ'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/div/section/div/ul/li[2]'))).click()

time.sleep(3)
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'LocationSearch_input')))
time.sleep(2)
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button.send_keys("Medellin, Antioquia")
button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/nav/div/div[1]/a[2]/span'))).click()
time.sleep(2)

temperatura = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//summary/div/div/div/span[@class='DetailsSummary--tempValue--1K4ka']")
temperatura = [temperatura.text for temperatura in temperatura]

horasT = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div/h3")
horasT = [horasT.text for horasT in horasT]

driver.quit()

indx = datetime.datetime.now()
indx = int(indx.strftime('%H'))
indx = (24 - indx)

sHoras = []
[sHoras.append(hora) for hora in horasT if hora not in sHoras]
horas = []
for i in range(0, indx):
    horas.append(sHoras[i])
```

THE ERROR IS IN THE VARIABLES NAME "sHoras"

Comment: Before anyone dives into those long, long xpaths: what are you after?  What's your ultimate goal? Are you trying to get **Hourly Weather-Medellín, Antioquia, Colombia** - the weather for this location, hourly?

Comment: Yes only that, the thing is, the error that it shows is for the variable, it says "Undifined varible". I said that is an empty list, but when I do the list comprehension it says that is undefined.

Comment: The problem was the list comprehension. I fix it like this:  `sHoras = []
    for hora in sHoras:
        if hora not in horasT:
            sHoras.append(hora)`

Comment: You didn't assigned that list comprehension to any variable. In any case, glad you sorted it out. You should consider improving your locators,  though, those long xpaths are quite fragile. Selenium docs can be of help: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/